# NestJS/Mongoose - query inside hooks

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I want to create slug from a title and execute a query to check if the slug exists. I tried to do it in a pre hook of save function, but I can't seem to find a way to execute a query. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281680/how-to-query-from-within-mongoose-pre-hook-in-a-node-js-express-app#answer-26268156) solution, but when I try to call any schema query function I get the following error:  `Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Function'.ts`.

This is just an example of the code I am trying to run:

```
export const CodeBlockSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(CodeBlock);
CodeBlockSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.slug = slugify(this.title.toLowerCase());
  const Item = this.constructor;
  Item.find({ name: this.title }).count().exec();
  next();
});
```

My module is in another class, and I found some solutions with importing module, but I am new with nestjs and don't think that is an elagant solution. Is it possible to access the schema query inside a hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with casting:

```
const codeBlockModule = <Model<CodeBlock>>this.constructor;
```